# Combining two physical drives into a logical one

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I currently have a 1TB hard drive when I store all my media - music, movies, etc. It's getting quite crowded so I want to buy another hard drive. However, I would like to  add new space to the current drive and not create a new one (i.e., all the files should be under drive letter `Q`, for example).

Is there any way to do this?

**EDIT**: to clarify, the drive I store my media in (the one I wish to expand) is not used for anything else - Windows is installed on a different drive.

**EDIT 2:** Also, the drives are not the same size, if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine them into a virtual RAID array (software raid) in the Windows Disk Management application. However, (AFAIK!) you can't do that to a system drive, NOR do this if the drive is already in use.

If you have a RAID capable motherboard, you can also use RAID0 to 2x the performance and size, but you also double the chance of something goes wrong (bla bla.. well.. backup regularly).

So no, I don't think there is an easy way to do this.
You can use "NTFS Junctions" and "hard links", but that's not exactly what you want.  (Basically that would make you have a folder on C: (for example) which in reality is on D:.)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link

Comment: "backup regularly" Have you ever tried backing up over a TB of video data...?

Comment: @Matt: That's what the "expert says". And no, never. I use RAID0 and I don't cry if I lose stuff. All the important data is stored in a Wuala synced folder. Everything else is replaceable, disposable.

Comment: Also, if those videos are IMPORTANT, use a NAS device with raid1 or just build a raid1 array in the PC.

Comment: The media I store is replaceable, and I don't want/need to back it up. So, I have to format the current drive to use RAID?

Comment: Yes, so first you will need a 1TB device where you can store your stuff until you make the RAID array. (However, if you don't have a RAID capable motherboard, you can NOT do this to a system drive. (you may have to buy a smaller (?) system drive too.))

Comment: Oh. EDIT2: Forget about what I said. You can't do that with RAID. You need the exact same size, (and it's better if they are the same series-model.)

Comment: @Shiki actually, I can manage with a new drive of the same size, If I can combine it easily. What about using hardware RAID? How does one use that?

Comment: @Amir - Tell me / us your motherboard's exact name / manufacturer. That way one can check if it got any kind of RAID capability.